# Display terms in relation to the terms of the page

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I created product sheets related to the terms of taxonomy. How to display a block of view, the products in relations with the currently visited page?
For example if my page is linked with the term "soap" requires that all products associated with the term "soap" appear in the block view.

I made a block view with a pop filter "tid" but I do not know how to parameterize.

version D7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a view of your products

2) Under Advanced, add a RELATIONSHIP of Taxonomy terms on node

- Checkmark ☑ require relationship

3) Add a CONTEXTUAL Filter of Has taxonomy term ID

- Select provide default value
- Select Taxonomy term ID from URL
- Checkmark ☑ load default filter from node page